# Reading from serial port with pyserial only works if terminal app is open in background

Tags: python, macos, pyserial, ftdi

I am using pyserial to communicate with my Multimeter (Keithley2000) over an FTDI based usb-to-rs232 adapter (Using the Mac OS X built-in driver).

Before I started with Pyserial I verified that the Hardware & Driver works by using a terminal app ([Serial.app](https://www.decisivetactics.com/products/serial/)) to communicate with the Multimeter.
*This works just fine.*

But if I try the same thing with the simple program below, it doesn't work.
Writing works fine (I can for example reset the instrument), but I can't read anything back.

```
import serial
import io

port = serial.Serial("/dev/cu.usbserial-FT8VXG35", 9600, timeout=1)
port.write("*idn?\r")
print(port.readline())
```

**Now here comes the weird part. If i leave Serial.app open in den background, the program actually works.**

Does anyone know the reason for this behaviour?

Here are my settings in Serial.app

[image: Settings]
[image: Settings]

Comment: RS232 has what are called flow control lines (RTS/CTS, DSR/DTR, there are some others, depends what your USB<>RS232 device implements) as well as the rx/tx data lines. Some peripherals pay attention to these and need them at specific levels before they will transmit. Maybe having serial.app open in the background sets these lines to something acceptable to your multimeter? I've never looked, does the python serial module let you control the flow control lines?

Comment: Have you tried a python serial terminal app, if that works maybe you can make the same settings on the port as it does?

Comment: Two excellent suggestions. I tried minterm.py (Which is part of pyserial) and at first it didn't work either, so I played around with RTS and DTR. Forcing RTS to low seems to do the trick. Adding `port.setRTS(False)` to the code above, it will make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some peripherals need the flow control lines (RTC/CTS, DSR/DTR) set to specific levels - maybe having serial.app running the background sets these lines the way your multimeter needs?